# Jquery animate background

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

i am using jquery to change child div's background when hovering main div.

```
$('#bottom-a .module.responsive').hover(function () {
    $('#bottom-a .responsive .mod-icon').css({
        "background-position": "left bottom"
    });
}, function () {
    $('#bottom-a .responsive .mod-icon').css({
        "background-position": "left top"
    });
});
```

How to add animation to this script? Thanx!

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery Animate function? http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: yes, but can't put it together, a bit drunk today so it is hard to think :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply with css without modifying your code :

```
#bottom-a .responsive .mod-icon {
    background-image:url('imgurl.jpg');
    transition: background 2s;
    -moz-transition: background  2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: background 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: background 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: ...CSS3 add a lot of power, now often is possible to obtain amazing effects only using css and without Javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bottom-a .module.responsive').hover(function () {
    $('#bottom-a .responsive .mod-icon').animate({
        "background-position": "left bottom"
    },1000);
}, function () {
    $('#bottom-a .responsive .mod-icon').animate({
        "background-position": "left top"
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution require jQuery UI?